# Objective-C - NSTimer: unrecognized selector sent to class - call method from another class

Tags: objective-c, selector, nstimer

addCloudOne is a method within the Food class. The following code produces a crash with the following error:

+[Food addCloudOne]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1000ad760

```
    SEL selector = @selector(addCloudOne);
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:k1 target:[Food class] selector:selector userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Do you have ideas?

Comment: You should give `instance` reference rather than `class` to target as `addCloudOne` might be an `instance method`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an instance of the `Food` class, so this argument is incorrect:

```
target:[Food class]
```

So what you are passing to `NSTimer` is a `Class` object, not a `Food` object.

Instead you probably need an instance variable of the `Food` instance and specify that:

```
@interface MyClass ()
{
    Food *_food;
}

@implementation MyClass
...
- (void)whatever
{
    _food = [Food new];             // This might need to be elsewhere
    SEL selector = @selector(addCloudOne);
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:k1
                                     target:_food
                                   selector:selector
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}
```